# Ordering results in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Iam trying to make a simple ordering using objectify and GAE. Unfortunatly it does't work. here is a simple example

```
class Book{  
     int publishYear;  
     long price;  
}
```

According to google, you have to order the field that you made your inequality filtering on it. so i did the following

```
query.filter("publishYear >=", year)  
query.order("publishYear")
```

then i want to order with price so i added the line

```
query.order("price")
```

but nothing is happening. I tried on different fields, it seems you can make only one order per query. Although this example says something different

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries

Anybody has a clue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objectify documentation says:

> To run queries by filtering or sorting
>   against multiple properties (that is,
>   if it can't be satisfied by a zigzag
>   merge on single-property indexes), you
>   must create a multi-value index in
>   your datastore-indexes.xml. There is a
>   great deal written on this subject; we
>   recommend [How Entities and Indexes are
>   Stored](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.html) and [Index Building](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building.html).

Hope it will helps.